# Changing text output dynamically - React native

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, websocket, fetch

## Question

How do I update my text/images every time my server updates.

## What I would like to have happen

1. Server adds text to DB
2. Server messages RN app using Web sockets
3. RN app requests data from server
4. Server requests data from DB
5. Server Sends data to RN app
6. RN app updates the `<ScrollView>` with the new data

## What does happen

1. Server adds text to DB
2. Server messages RN app using Web sockets
3. RN app requests data from server
4. Server requests data from DB
5. Server Sends data to RN app

NOTE: I **know** that the server sends the correct data to the RN app and that the app receives the data. I have `console.log`ed it.

## Data

Here is an example of the data that is sent from the server to the RN app:

```
[ { _id: 592f7a5c74376a749e2db211,
    name: 'world',
    allowedUsers: [ '114135152003891444692', '114135152003891444692' ],
    firstUser: '114135152003891444692',
    imageSrcList:
     [ 'hello world',
       'hello moon',
       '',
       'images/WedMay31201720:38:57GMT-0700(PDT)MILI1496288337083myUserName.jpg' ] },

  { _id: 592f8bf462d68f777dd47cfb,
    name: 'hello',
    allowedUsers: [ '114135152003891444692', '114135152003891444692' ],
    firstUser: '114135152003891444692',
    imageSrcList:
     [ 'foo',
       'bar',
       '',
       'images/WedMay31201720:39:01GMT-0700(PDT)MILI1496288341061myUserName.jpg' ] } ]
```

It consists of an array of objects.

Each object consists of:

- `_id` an identifier that is unique
- `name` an individual name, it can be duplicated
- `allowedUsers` and array of the allowed users
- `firstUser` the first user - and the user that started the "pool"
- `imageSrcList` this consists of the URLs for the images and the chat
  messages, this is where I need help.

## How I would like the app to interpret the data.

Each "pool" is an object inside of the above array. I would like to have the app display all of the "chat" text, and the images from the `imageSrcList` when the user clicks on the "pool".

#### How it should go about this

(in my opinion - if you know of a better way by all means share!)

1. Sorts through the array to find the right "pool"
2. Sorts through each element of the `imageSrcList` to find which are photos and which are chat messages.
3. Adds the necessary JSX code (eg. `<Text>` or `<Image/>`)
4. Pushes to an output array
5. Displays the output array in a `<ScrollView>`

## Current solution

This solution does not work, but it should help you understand what I am trying to do.

```
loadData(cb) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/home/' + this.state.user.id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseText) => {
      console.log('done laoding inicial data: ');
      console.log(responseText.pools);
      console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params._id);
      cb(responseText.pools)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ myValues: error, loaded: true, });
    });
  }
```

... and

```
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log('MESSAGE');
      this.loadData(function(listObj){
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          if (listObj[i]._id === params._id){
            params.list = listObj[i].imageSrcList;
            console.log(listObj[i].imageSrcList);
          }
        }
        list = params.list;
        output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          if ( (typeof list[i] === 'string') && (list[i].includes('.jpg')) ){
            output.push(<Image
              style={styles.preview}
              source={{uri: 'http://localhost:8000/' + list[i] }}
            />);
          }else if( typeof list[i] === null ){
            output.push();
          }else if ( list[i] === ''){
            output.push()
          }else{
            output.push(<Text>{list[i]}</Text>);
          }
        }
      });
    };
```

... and

```
<ScrollView
            ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
            onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{
                this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
            }}>{output}</ScrollView>
```

## More info

- I am using React Native
- I am using IOS
- I am using NodeJS/Express for the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way of doing this which would work is:

1) Save the response from `loadData` to state

```
loadData(cb) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/home/' + this.state.user.id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseText) => {
        this.setState({ pools: responseText.pools, loaded: true });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ myValues: error, loaded: true, });
    });
}
```

2) Create a `_renderTools` method:

```
_renderPools() {
    const output = [];
    // The data from the server can be accessed using this.state.pools
    // Do your magic stuff here and populate output with <Text> elements
    return output;
}
```

3) Reference output in you `render` method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this._renderPools()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do, I spent most of yesterday banging my head agains the wall trying to figure out the best way to do this. Also, I think you want to change `_renderTools()` to `_renderPools()`, but I still got the idea. thanks agian

Comment: Hey @pudility thanks! Yeah, I changed it to _renderPools :)